# In WebStorm, how do I disable props indentation in React?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, auto-indent

In WebStorm, by default indentation for React functional component props is to align it with the opening curly brace.

```
export default function TableSeater({
                                    sectionsLookup, tableSelectionList
}: IProps) {
```

How can I make it align normally by default, like this?

```
export default function TableSeater({
  sectionsLookup, tableSelectionList
}: IProps) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling Align when multiline for Function declaration parameters in Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Wrapping and Braces: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i4ov.png)